# What does "I am busting" mean?

Tags: meaning

I was watching Seinfeld and whenever things start becoming great for George (he is always jobless and miserable) he says : "I am busting".

Does it mean breaking the bad luck or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Busting" is a synonym for "bursting." When George says he's busting, he means he's "bursting with emotion" (see ["a sudden expression or manifestation, as of emotion"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/burst?s=t)). It doesn't have anything to do with breaking the cycle of bad luck (although that's certainly a factor in his emotions); he just means he's really happy.

Comment: Do you have any idea what, if any, the geographic distribution of this is? ‘I’m busting!’ sounds quite unnatural to me, as do examples like ‘laughing fit to bust’ or ‘busting to pee’—but they all seem quite common if Google is to be trusted. I would personally **always** use _burst_ rather than _bust_ here and would probably even have corrected them if I’d seen them in a text I was proofreading.

Comment: Offhand, no, I'm not sure what the distribution looks like. "I'm busting!" isn't part of my regular lexicon either. I've heard it enough that it doesn't sound unnatural, but personally I don't think I've ever said it. I'll have to look into the distribution and isogloss when I have some time to do so, but if anyone else knows something, that information would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

By "I am busting" , he probably means to ***evade out of the situation*** as his luck always runs out whenever things start becoming great.